# How to migrate laravel website to codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, laravel-5.3

I have a website which was created in laravel 5.3. But the hosting server is not supporting php 7 or above. So i wish to convert the project to code-igniter. Is there any possibilities to convert

Comment: No! Why don't you change your hosting?

Comment: Why dont you find another hosting provider and save a lot of time? Google cloud compute engine would be cheaper and create your own configurations.

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic means to convert code base of one framework to another one. The only way to "migrate" is to rewrite your website from scratch. But I don't think you'd want to do that if your PHP part is complex.

Like others in the comment area, I'd recommend changing to PHP 7 hosting instead of rewriting your PHP code.

If you absolutely need to do it (instead of changing to any [PHP 7 hosting](https://wp-me.com/best-php-7-wordpress-hosting/)), you should look for automatic code generator like [CRUDigniter](http://www.crudigniter.com) or library like [Grocery CRUD](https://www.grocerycrud.com/) to reduce your work.